# rigging mesh to bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

newB here so, i am probably getting everything all wrong so please bear with me.

I am working on a model of Jesus with intent of 3D printing my pose but I am getting no results in the parenting of mesh and armature.  It seems that nothing is linking together.

I have been following this [excellent tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYgznqvbisM) on youtube and everything up to the timestamp 46:40 has gone without a hitch.  but confusion has set in and seeking help is my only recourse.

Granted my model I found on a google search for free stl.  So, it may not even be the direction I should be headed.  Any advice is awesome.

[image]

Comment: You can share your file by going to https://blend-exchange.com/ and following the instructions there.

Comment: @JohnEason this appears to be an answer, not a comment. Please add it as such.

Comment: As noted, loose parts and disconnected pieces will stop automatic weighting from working. There was probably an error in the lower right hand side of the blender window, but you just didn’t see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried to parent the bones to your model you would have briefly seen an error in the middle of the bottom status bar:
"Bone Heat Weight: failed to find a solution for one or more bones."
Select your model in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode, go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then hit <kbd>A</kbd> which will select All. Now hit <kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>Merge by Distance</kbd>. If you look at the status bar as you select the merge, you'll see that it's removed over 38000 duplicate vertices. You can now parent your rig to the object again and you'll find that it now works when you go into Pose mode. The object obviously wasn't made to be posed because the cloak is actually part of the arms, so the results may not be as good as you hope.

Comment: thank you for the advice.  it is too obvious that i have a long way to go.  just getting a start in blender and hope to become somewhat proficient.  so glad i stumbled upon this site.  a valuable resource for someone in my fledgling status.  i can see that i will be back again and again.  once more, thank you John.  that helped immensely.  and yes, i figured the model may not be suitable for my needs but had to start somewhere. right? lol